# Хорошие манеры при создании web-проекта

Tags: php, mysql, project

## Привет. Расскажу коротко, что я хочу сделать и что мне понадобится.

Я хочу сделать что-то вроде *"соц.сети"*, блог, форум, не знаю какой из терминов подобрать. Функциональность должна быть такая:

- Общение (чат)
- Страница профиля (фото профиля, доп. информация)
- Добавление новостей
- Друзья и прочее

Хостинг буду использовать https://gpdhost.com/, но не стану спешить.

---

Для начала, определимся о приоритетах:

- Безопасность **(внешняя)** *(запрет доступа к различным файлам)*
- Безопасность **(внутри)** *(безопасные запросы в БД и т.д.)*
- Использование не устаревших технологий
- Простота использования сайта *(дизайн и т.д.)*

Итак, с приоритетами определились. Приступаем к практике.

**Стоит ли мне делать так:**
Пользовательская часть будет лежать в папке `localhost`,
а серверная в - `app` (допустим)?
Если да, то как мне быть, если у меня на хостинге такая структура (главная папка `public_html`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а если нет, то может, это и хорошо.

---

**Теперь вопрос о безопасности (внешней).**
Как запретить доступ на просмотр файлов, но при условии, что они будут работать при подключении к другим файлам (`include_once 'файл, который нужно обезопасить';`).

### Ну и последний вопрос. В этом вопросе (тавтология:D), просто посоветуйте правильные манеры ведения таких веб-проектов. Как более профессионально сделать?

И насчет `.htaccess`, будет ли он работать на хостинге? Когда-то пробовал, что-то не все работало. Например страницы ошибок.

---

### Frameworks

Стоит ли мне браться за изучение фреймворка? Я понимаю, что костылей на ванильном php будет больше, чем надежд сделать что-то годное, но все же. Какой фреймворк вы посоветуете?

Comment: Более профессионально будет использовать фреймворки. Например Yii2, Laravel или Symfony. Как только начнёте изучать и использовать один из них - остальные вопросы и проблемы из этого вопроса исчезнут

Comment: @AlMr, поскольку я никогда не работал с этими фреймворками, можете коротко объяснить в чем разница между первым и вторым?

Comment: Думаю в данном вопросе лучше послушать мнения сразу нескольких людей. https://toster.ru/q/206825

Comment: Вот очень интересная и свежая статья о framework'ах в общем и Yii в частности: https://habrahabr.ru/post/333398/ , особенно интересно обсуждение которое она вызвала. Рекомендую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Стоит ли мне делать так:"  - обычно делают так. В корне веб сайта лежит index.php, который отвечает на все запросы и все что нужно для работы сайта - картинки, js, css . Код PHP сайта лежит в отдельной директории, иногда вне корня веб сайта, иногда внутри. Главное чтобы к нему из веба не было доступа. Попробуйте первый вариант - создать директорию на уровне public_html для кода. Если получится - будет первый вариант, иначе второй.

"Теперь вопрос о безопасности (внешней)" - способов много. Директория вне веб директории, запрет через настройки веб сервера, проверка наличия определенной константы в начале пхп файла. Эту константу задают в index.php и если такой константы нет - файл завершает работу.

"Как более профессионально сделать?" - использовать фреймворк, где все эти вопросы и многие другие уже решены. Yii2, Laravel

"И насчет .htaccess, будет ли он работать на хостинге?" - если у вас веб сервер апач, то, скорее всего, будут.

Comment: Можете коротко объяснить, на "хлопский ум", для чего нужны фрэймворки? Какую пользу они дают. Просто никогда не сталкивался с ними и вовсе не знаю, что и как.

Comment: Фреймворк - это решение стандартных задач стандартными средствами. Вместо того чтобы делать свой велосипед, сесть на готовый. Это плюс. Минус - фреймворк надо изучать и он может быть избыточен.